# Deactivate push-animation in segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, push, segue

I've one problem. I have a ViewController1 whcich opens the ViewController2 through a push-segue. //Both are NavigationControllers

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"show2"])
    {
        ViewController2 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

But is it possible to deactivate the animation of this push-action, so it directly shows the new ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do something like this?

```
[ViewController1 pushViewController:ViewController2 animated:NO];
```